# NGINX rewrite regex not working correctly

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

community,
I have a Problem and I can't find a solution. I have a website running in which you can open things. You can use the path: `https://localhost/open/index.htmp?id=1234` (or without the index.html in the URI). I want to open it throughout the path `https://localhost/open/1234`, so I set up a NGINX rewrite-rule:

```
rewrite "^/open/(?!\?id=.*)(.{1,})$" /open?id=$1 permanent; (I also tried last instead of permanent)
```

This rule, redirected me many times, so my path looked like `/open/?id=&id=&id=&id=&id=1234`
I also tried:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /?id=$request_uri
```

None of them worked. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need and cannot use the `(?!\?id=.*)` part in the `rewrite` directive, as Nginx uses a [normalised URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) when matching `location`, `try_files` and `rewrite` directives.

You could focus the regular expression to only match numeric IDs, for example:

```
rewrite ^/open/(\d+)$ /open/?id=$1 permanent;
```

The regular expression operator `+` is the same as `{1,}`.